# Unable to reset message status of extant message

Tags: surveymonkey

I have a message that I want to re-use each time I send out recipients.  The message currently has the status of "sent" as shown when I ask for the detail of the message.  After I send the new recipients, I attempt to set them message status by doing:

```
!curl --silent -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:bearer [Auth Key]" https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors/1234/messages/1234 '-d {"status":"not_sent"}'
```

(with 1234 being the appropriate collector and message numbers.  What I get back is an error "Invalid schema in the body provided".

Does anyone know how to reset the message status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages are not re-usable. If you want to send a reminder email you should create a new message of type `reminder` with the `recipient_status` set to the recipients you want to get the reminder email. Similarly if you want to create a new thank you email, you'll want to create a message with type `thank_you`.

If you're just trying to add new recipients to the message to take the survey, you'll have to create a new `invite` message with the new recipients. So you'll either want to have a template for your message and create a new message off that template or make a copy of a previous message:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages
{
    "from_collector_id": "<collector_id>",
    "from_message_id": "<message_id>",
    "include_recipients": false,
}
```

The problem with that is you'll need to keep track of messages. So depending on what you're trying to do, it may be easier to just have an HTML template stored somewhere to use for new messages.